How can I use CSS to create a clickable hover menu?
I am trying to build a page in html, and I have images overlayed by a transparent background on hover. The hover effect works well, but unfortunately, the links on the overlay are not clickable.
I would assume this has to do with the z-index. I have tried changing it, and was able to make the links clickable... but the hover effect became so jittery that actually clicking on the links was no longer possible. I believe this is the result of a circular error of sorts- when the z-index is high enough to make the links clickable, the page assumes I'm not hovering over the original object anymore, thus causing the jittering.
I know this is possible in Javascript, but I would like to see if there is a way to fix this in css.
Also, currently, my hover effects rely on having the b position as fixed.
Here is my code:


.grid {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3rem;
  background-color: rgb(3, 4, 39);
  color: white;
}

.linkhere.fill-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 475px;
  max-width: 900px;
  background-color: rgba(3, 4, 39, 0.6);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  h3 {
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(3, 4, 39, 0.6);
    padding: 1rem;
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    transition: transform .4s;
  }
  b {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20;
    left: 20;
    bottom: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
      ~.item__overlay {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
        h3 {
          transform: translate(0, 0);
        }
        .item__body {
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.item__overlay {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  transition: transform .4s;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(3, 4, 39, 0.6);
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
  pointer-events: all;
}

.item__body {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: rgba(3, 4, 39, 0.6);
  p {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
  }
  a {
    color: green;
  }
}
<div class="grid">
  <h1>Team Useful Links <a href="https://www.google.com"> additional link</a></h1>
</div>


<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">
    <b></b>
    <img src="ship1.jfif" alt=''>
    <div class="item__overlay">
      <h3>WSS Overall Links <a href="https://www.google.com"> additional link</a></h3>
      <div class="item__body">
        <p>tesxt</p>
        <p><a href="https://www.google.com">mytesthere</a></p>
        <p><a href="https://www.google.com">mytesthere</a></p>
        <p><a href="https://www.google.com">mytesthere</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <b></b>
    <img src="ship1.jfif" alt=''>
    <div class="item__overlay">
      <h3>Person Name 2</h3>
      <div class="item__body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <b></b>
    <img src="ship1.jfif" alt=''>
    <div class="item__overlay">
      <h3>Person with a really long name</h3>
      <div class="item__body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <b></b>
    <img src="ship1.jfif" alt=''>
    <div class="item__overlay">
      <h3>Person with an even longer name that wraps onto multiple lines</h3>
      <div class="item__body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <b></b>
    <img src="ship1.jfif" alt=''>
    <div class="item__overlay">
      <h3 id=>Image Hover Title 1</h3>
      <div class="item__body">
        <p>Sample Text Here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <b></b>
    <img src="ship1.jfif" alt=''>
    <div class="item__overlay">
      <h3 id=>Person Name 2</h3>
      <div class="item__body">
        <p>sample text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <b></b>
    <img src="ship1.jfif" alt=''>
    <div class="item__overlay">
      <h3>Person with a really long name</h3>
      <div class="item__body">
        <p>sample text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <b></b>
    <img src="ship1.jfif" alt=''>
    <div class="item__overlay">
      <h3>Person with an even longer name that wraps onto multiple lines</h3>
      <div class="item__body">
        <p>sample text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Undo the z-index change, and just apply the same styles that you are currently applying for b:hover ~ .item__overlay, for .item__overlay:hover as well.

That worked perfectly! Thank you so much~


Use position:absolute, top:0, left:0 for .item_overlay to cover the parent element.
update z-index:2 for the overlay so that it appears above all other elements.
update overlay transform to transform: translateY(100%), translateY(0) on hover to reveal the overlay.
for .item__overlay, update pointer-events: auto so that it can handle mouse events.

.grid {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3rem;
  background-color: rgb(3, 4, 39);
  color: white;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 475px;
  max-width: 900px;
  background-color: rgba(3, 4, 39, 0.6);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
}

.item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.item__overlay {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(3, 4, 39, 0.6);
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  color: white;
  pointer-events: auto;
  z-index: 2;
}

.item:hover .item__overlay {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.item__body {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: rgba(3, 4, 39, 0.6);
}

.item__body p {
  margin: 0;
}

.item__body a {
  color: green;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(3, 4, 39, 0.6);
  padding: 1rem;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: transform 0.4s;
}

.item:hover h3 {
  transform: translateY(0);
}


Unexplained code dumps aren't considered good answers.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
